# How do I recover a unsaved portions of a word 2011 document on Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I am a Mac user and am working on a paper with Word 2011. I was last working on it a couple days ago and saved it to my desktop. I'm certain of this because I later reopened it to keep working . Today though I opened the document and 95% of my work was lost. The document was still there, but worked which I had previously saved was no where to be found. I checked everywhere including in hidden auto recovery folder of Library. Please anyone let me know if you can help!

Comment: Did you try Time Machine?

Comment: Wow thank you! That recovered a good chunk of my missing work, but I'm still missing some. Can you think of any other way to get the rest?

Comment: I'm by no means certain, but as far as I'm aware, the MS Word auto-save/recovery data is stored within the file itself, so once the session is ended, it is cleared.

Comment: so that would mean there is most likely no way of recovering what I am still missing?

Comment: I would be doubtful - though someone may know better. In the meantime, investigation of what went wrong may be useful - perms & disk integrity check from Disk Utility.

Comment: Okay I'll look into that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome & fingers crossed for you.